# How to have a new keymap not block an existing one?

Tags: key-bindings

There is a built-in mapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> which presents the current filename immediately in the command area. I would like to augment this by tapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> again to copy the filename to my system clipboard register.

At the moment, I have added this to my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-g><c-g> :let @+=@%<CR>
```

However, this has the downside of delaying the presentation of the filename when only one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> sequence is used. Is it possible to make it so one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> immediately shows the filename and the second copies it to a register?

Comment: The problem is one of common prefixes: vim has to wait until you type further keys or a delay has passed to decide what command you entered.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yup and I rely on that feature too and I think it makes a lot of sense for it be the default. In this case, as all the actions build on each other and are harmless, I was hoping there is a way to opt-out and just immediately apply each action in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The current buffer name is already in a register `:h quote_%`:

```
:echo @%
```

> Is it possible to make it so one Ctrl-g immediately shows the filename and the second copies it to a register?

No, it doesn't make sense. You could rather make one c-g do both. For example,

```
nnoremap <silent><C-G> :let @+=@%<CR><C-G>
```

Though this simplistic attempt also breaks `{count}<c-g>`.

Comment: I'm copying it to the `+` register because that is my system clipboard and it is useful for pasting into other applications. However, I will update my question to use the shortened form which I just tried and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is just for fun:

```
func! MyCg() abort
    func! s:timer_handle(t) abort closure
        unlet b:myctrlg
    endfunc
    if get(b:, "myctrlg", v:true)
        exe "normal! \<c-g>"
        let b:myctrlg = v:false
        call timer_start(500, {t -> s:timer_handle(t)})
    else
        let b:myctrlg = v:true
        let @+ = @%
    endif
endfunc
nnoremap <silent><C-g> :call MyCg()<CR>
```

- `<C-g><C-g>` echo what a single `<C-g>` does and copy filename to `+` register (should be pressed with less than 500ms timeout).
- `<C-g>` does usual `<C-g>` things.